# Use glob to match files without a file extension

Tags: python, import, glob

I am trying to use glob to match all the files in a folder. All the files start with the same word but I forgot to include .txt at the end of them. Is there a way to write the code to get all of these files despite the fact there is no file extension in my directory?

Comment: Are you familiar with what the wildcards mean in glob? https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html I assume you use the pattern `*.*`. If you want all files, just omit the `.*` part of your glob pattern. If your directory contains files with and without extensions and you want _only_ files that do not have an extension, then that is a more complicated pattern

Comment: Your question should include specific examples of problematic data. Can you paste a list of files, possibly with full pathname?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure if that is what you want, but this will get all the files/folders that start with the word "california" in the same directory.

So if no folders start with "california" in your directory this will do it

```py
import glob, os

for file_ in glob.glob('california*'):
    os.rename(file_, file_+'.csv')
```

output1: `['california_housing_train', 'california_housing_test']`

output2: `['california_housing_train.csv', 'california_housing_test.csv']`

Comment: This is what I needed. I ran this twice by accident and now all my files are .txt.txt. Is there a way to rename them so the extra txt is removed?

Comment: `os.rename(file_, file_.replace('.csv', '', 1))` this will remove one of the ".csv.csv" dont forget the 1 it indicates remove only one of the two ".csv"

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want to add a `.txt` file extension from the way you worded your question. You can use a wildcard character (`*`) anywhere in your glob expression

```
import glob
import shutil

for file in glob.glob('/path/to/files/commonWord*'):
    shutil.move(file, file + '.txt')
```

Comment: This is what I needed. I ran this twice by accident and now all my files are .txt.txt. Is there a way to rename them so the extra txt is removed?

Answer (score 0):

You can take them all and then check by regex whether or not it has an extension and add the file to a list or whatever you want.

```
import glob
import re

files = glob.glob('*')

for file in files:
    if not re.findall(r'.*\.[a-z]+',file):
        print(file)
```